# Download file using webclient

Tags: .net, webclient, download

I try to download a file from https site and every time the file is saved to my machine it is only 1KB. The file is supposed to be 1MB. I am using Webclient.

```
string strFile = @"c:\myfile.txt";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userid", "pw");
wc.DownloadFile("https://www.mysite.come/myfile.txt", strFile);
```

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the text?  Is it the first 1K of the file, or something else?

Comment: woa, 6 question, none accepted... you should do something about it

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK WebClient by default does not put the User-Agent string, this could annoy servers; try

```
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "XXX");
```

where you can pick up XXX from [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/).

Comment: What is XXX please?  Is it https address?

Comment: I modified the codes and it seems to give me the information file, not the file I want.
string strFile = @"c:\myfile.txt";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "https://www.mysite.come/");
wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userid", "pw");
wc.DownloadFile("https://www.mysite.come/myfile.txt", strFile);

Comment: no XXX is the user agent string, not the address: it's how a browser identifies itself to a http server; scripts may decide to "block" requests according to the user agent. The user agent string looks like "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en-GB) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10" or whatever. It is better if it matches the one of a real browser

Comment: Thank you. In my case this was the issue... i was using HTTPS, and tried everything. I never thought this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is your permissions mate, I am having the same problem, yet no one seems to want to help 100% of the way... By permissions I mean your OS is not allowing the file to be downloaded into the directory that is why it is only 1KB.

I have gotten somewhere with it incidentally, `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]`

I will keep an eye on this thread because there is a tag that has to be added, that I have searched for but have not found as of yet, I will keep you up to date.

Comment: +1 - someone should of pointed out that saving files to a root directory is just plain stupid